# Expectation of sum pf products

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expected-value

We roll a fair dice over and over, until we get number $1$.

What is the expected value of the sum of all products?

--

Define $X$ - sum of all products, $X_i$ - number of toss $i$,

we are basically looking for  $$X=\prod_{i=0}^\infty X_i$$

But how do I calculate $E(X)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Take the logarithm of your product in order to work with sums.

Comment: That is not a "sum of products". It is a "product series".

Comment: Second, the series is not infinite: it stops on the first roll of '1' which should almost certainly happen after a finite count.  (Hint: The count of rolls is geometrically distributed)

Comment: You are not clear. What do you mean by **sum of products** ? Is the random variable you are studying $X := X_1+X_1X_2+\cdots +(X_1X_2...X_{i-1})$ if the $i$th throw gives a $1$ ???

Comment: Do you mean "outcome of dice toss" by "product"?